# Ubuntu + Install Ruby 1.9, Rails 3 Using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rvm

Best way to Install `RUBY 1.9, Rails 3, Postgres, Heroku, GitHub,` Using RVM

Can anyone suggest me the best way in which,I follow to install it properly, because previously I felt in various dependencies issues.

Suggest something !!!

Comment: best way for urgent case is to hire professional admin

Comment: Anyways, it sound like wrong question .... Okay.. Thanks for correcting me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you get Ruby and Rails set up step by step from my guide here http://www.aaginskiy.com/technology/2011/12/install-rails-3-1-from-scratch/

Postgresql and Heroku can be installed as gems by running `gem install _____`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to follow [this guide](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) wrote by Ryan Bigg. You will be able to quickly setup your system for RVM + Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails.

Then have a look at [heroku quick start guide](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) to setup and learn how to use Heroku.

Answer (score 3):

I followed this [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) to install RVM and it worked for me fine. After installing RVM you can install Ruby as well (without problems). After this, create gemset for your ruby version and execute `gem install rails` - Rails will be installed. Then `gem install heroku`.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-rvm nodejs #nodejs is javascript runtime, rails needs one

sudo rvm package install openssl #it doesn't work with stock openssl

sudo rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr

sudo rvm --default use 1.9.2 #sets the default version of ruby to use in rvm-shell

rvm-shell

rvmsudo gem install rails #rvmsudo is the way to go, sudo doesn't access the environment
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10.
You have to use the rvm-shell in order to access the proper environment.

Answer (score -1):

use homebrew (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) to install Postgres, once you've got Homebrew installed you'd just do `brew install postgresql` and follow the instructions

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu, the best way to install is to **not use RVM**. Ruby 1.9 is in the repositories - use them. Everything else is a gem.

Comment: I disagree. RVM is a much better experience on Ubuntu.

Comment: RVM is version manager and Ruby 1.9 is setup for installation. Then how can it works like RVM ? Please clarify it, if it is right.

Comment: Just install the ruby1.9.1 package. Then use update-alternatives to link /usr/bin/ruby to /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1.